# Webview Splash screen doen't show once as expected

Tags: java, android, webview, splash-screen

Am trying to create a webview app displaying a splash screen once after the first lunch. Initially once i open the app the splash screen will show up then after 5 seconds it will load main activity `VaultActivity`, but after i have added the line of code to check if splash screen 'SplashScreen' has been launched  before, the app stopped loading `VaultActivity` using the `SPLASH_TIME_OUT` i set and also the splash screen still shows up anytime i lunch the app.

**Initially**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;  // Splash screen timer

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Start main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, VaultActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
}
```

**Currently**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;  // Splash screen timer

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Start main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, VaultActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        } else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Manifest**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".VaultActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/androidmobile" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> :) you need just adding startActivity in else section.

```
   public class SplashScreen extends Activity {



            private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;  // Splash screen timer

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit()
                if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
                    //ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                    //ed.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, VaultActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                } else {
                   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Start main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, VaultActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                    ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                    ed.commit();

                            finish();
                        }
                    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: not yet, i just tested it and it doesn't lunch the splash screen on first lunch then on the next lunch it does

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the startActivity in your else.